# Simple Framer Motion animation not working in NextJS project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, framer-motion

In my `nextjs` project [v13, pages directory] I tried to add the [following animation](https://blog.maximeheckel.com/snippets/2020-7-3-waving-hand-animation-framer-motion/) to my hero component, but for some reason I'm getting a static emoji instead of a waving animation.

[image: I'm getting a static emoji instead of a waving animation]

This is my `WavingHand` component:

```
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

export default function WavingHand() {
  return (
    <motion.div
      style={{
        marginBottom: '-20px',
        marginRight: '-45px',
        paddingBottom: '20px',
        paddingRight: '45px',
        display: 'inline-block',
      }}
      animate={{ rotate: 20 }}
      transition={{
        yoyo: Infinity,
        from: 0,
        duration: 0.2,
        ease: 'easeInOut',
        type: 'tween',
      }}
    >
      
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

and this is my chunk of code in `Hero` component where I'm calling the `WavingHand` component which is then called in the `index.js` homepage:

```
<Typography
  component={motion.h1}
  variant="h1"
  sx={{
    fontSize: { md: '4rem', sm: '3rem', xs: '3rem' },
    textAlign: { xs: 'center', sm: 'initial' },
  }}
>
  Hello <WavingHand /> !
</Typography>;
```

Also tried wrapping the entire `Typography` element in a `motion.div` wrapper, but it still won't animate, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the rotate needs be in an array of keyframes, also the transition property should be inside animate object.

Here's the working snippet:

```
export default function WavingHand() {
    return (
        <div
            style={{
                marginBottom: "-20px",
                marginRight: "-45px",
                paddingBottom: "20px",
                paddingRight: "45px",
                display: "inline-block",
            }}
            animate={{
                rotate: [0, 20, 0], // Add an array to specify the animation keyframes
                transition: {
                    yoyo: Infinity,
                    duration: 0.2,
                    ease: "easeInOut",
                    type: "tween",
                },
            }}
        >
            
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

**Here's a breakdown:**

- Uses inline styles for defining the animation properties.
- The animate property is an object with rotate as an array to specify keyframes for rotation.
- The animation is set to yoyo infinitely, with a
  duration of 0.2 seconds and an easing of "easeInOut".

Hope it helped!

Comment: It still didn't work, I don't think the actual problem is with the waving hand component,  something is breaking when I call it in the hero component

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `yoyo:Infinity` doesn't work in the current `framer-motion` version, the following code works:

```
<motion.div
  style={{
    marginBottom: "-20px",
    marginRight: "-45px",
    paddingBottom: "20px",
    paddingRight: "45px",
    display: "inline-block",
  }}
  animate={{ rotate: [0, 20, 0] }}
  transition={{
    duration: 1,
    ease: "easeInOut",
    repeat: Infinity,
    repeatDelay: 0,
  }}

</motion.div>
```